# Contrapositive of Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

We have that if $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is differentiable and its jacobian $J_f$ is nonzero at a point $p$, then $f$ is invertible in a n-hood of $p$. By the contrapositive, if $f$ is not invertible in a n-hood of $p$, then $J_f(p)=0$. But there is the example where $f=(e^x\cos y, e^x\sin y)$ with $J_f=e^{2x}$. Here $f$ is not invertible over its entire image since, for instance, $f(x_0,y_0)=f(x_0,y_0+2\pi)$, so $f$ is not $1-1$. So the inverse of $f$ is not defined at $f(x_0,y_0)=f(x_0,y_0+2\pi)$, and so using the contrapositive, in particular, we have that $J_f(x_0,y_0+2\pi)=0$. But $J_f=e^{2x}$ is never zero! wth?

Comment: that is a local property i.e. in each point there exists a neighborhood such that $f$ is invertible

Comment: So do I need to write the N-hood part in terms of ``there exists small $\epsilon>0$ s.t....'', so that the contrapositive now reads ``if for all $\epsilon>0$ ... s.t. $f$ is not invertible, then...''?

Comment: what is your question? What does "*wth?*" mean?

Comment: @Mirko What the hell?

Comment: @Yeah.. Thank you, at least now I got the question ... but "wth" seems a bit vague, don't know how to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just because the Jacobian is never zero doesn't mean that the function is invertible over in it's entire image.  It just means that there exists a neighborhood around each point in the domain for which $f$ is invertible.

The converse would read something like this:

For a continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $p$ in it's domain, if there does not exist an n-hood of $p$ wherein $f$ is invertible then $J_f (p) = 0$.

So to use this you could first show that for every ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered on $p$ $f$ is not invertible.  Every neighborhood will contain one of these balls thus you have shown that $f$ is not invertible in every neighborhood of $p$. Then you can use the converse of the inverse function theorem to conclude that $J_f (p) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The neighborhood on which the function is invertible may need to be taken small. If the function is not invertible in a large neighborhood, this does not mean that there is no smaller neighborhood on which the functions is invertible.

The contrapositive is not that 
"if $f$ is not invertible in a n-hood of $p$, etc." (i.e. on some neigborhood).

The contrapositive is that 
"if $f$ is not invertible in *any* n-hood of $p$, etc." (i.e. for every neighborhood of $p$, $f$ is not invertible on that neigborhood).

$\neg\exists N, (f$ is invertible on $N)$ means:
$\forall N, \neg (f$ is invertible on $N)$ , i.e. :
for *every* neighborhood $N$, the function $f$ is *not* invertible on $N$.